# Why is comparing same objects values using if statement or assertj always gives error?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, maven-plugin

I subtracted two Objects using another class, but when I return the new value and compare to the expected value, it's gives error even when it's the same value(I think).

I tried to use if statement but same thing.

```
   if(expected.current_Money.toString().equals(0.5)){
        System.out.println(" if statmenet is working...");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
```

Imports in that first class(Prefer not to change it).

```
   import org.assertj.core.api.ThrowableAssert;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
   import java.math.BigDecimal;

   import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
   import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy;
```

On the same file, we have this method.

```
@Test
void subtract_two_money_should_be_correct() {
    Money oneDinar = new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
    Money halfDinar = new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5));
    System.out.println("Value of oneDinar 
    "+oneDinar.current_Money.toString());
    System.out.println("Value of halfDinar 
    "+halfDinar.current_Money.toString());

    //Money expected = oneDinar.subtract(halfDinar);
    Money expected = new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5));

    System.out.println("the Value of Expected 
    "+expected.current_Money.toString());

    assertThat(expected).isEqualTo(new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5)));
}
```

The output of subtracted is saved to an object and have variable inside has datatype BigDecimal .

On the other file.
Imports

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

We have these fields(variables inside the second class.

```
    public static final Money HALF_DINAR = new 
  Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5));


    public static final Money QUARTER_DINAR = new 
  Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.25)) ;
    public static final Money DINAR = new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
    public BigDecimal current_Money;
```

Here is the last thing, the method we used to subtract.

```
  public Money subtract(Money SubtractMoney) {
            System.out.println("TheValue of current money "+current_Money.toString());
            Money current = new Money(current_Money);
            System.out.println("TheValue of current  "+current.current_Money.toString());

            BigDecimal subtractedNumber = current_Money.subtract(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(SubtractMoney.current_Money)));
            System.out.println("TheValue of subtractedNumber"+subtractedNumber.toString());

            Money newMoney = new Money(subtractedNumber);
            System.out.println("TheValue of newMoney "+newMoney.current_Money.toString());

            return newMoney ;
        }
```

I expect the output will be same as that object(in numbers is the same, but it's give me wrong even if i used if statement or Assertthat.

I expect output is true and no errors.
also the number is 0.5 which is the goal.

Output:

```
Value of oneDinar 1
Value of halfDinar 0.5
TheValue of current money 1
TheValue of current  1
TheValue of subtractedNumber0.5
TheValue of newMoney 0.5
the Value of Expected 0.5

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
 <com.progressoft.induction.Money@123f1134>
to be equal to:
 <com.progressoft.induction.Money@7d68ef40>
but was not.
Expected :com.progressoft.induction.Money@7d68ef40
Actual   :com.progressoft.induction.Money@123f1134
```

Comment: Based on the output you are trying to compare two different instances Money which can be identified by the `@123f1134` and `@7d68ef40`. The question is: Is this really what you like to compare?

Comment: The `subtract` method is not the important part here. The important part is whether the class `Money` has correctly implemented `equals()` method (and matching `hashCode()` to boot, read Javadoc for those for more details).

Comment: @khmarbaise, Yes I want to compare them if they have the same values, then assertthat will be true, otherwise it will output an error.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks. It's solved my problem by overriding equals and hashcode(used apache common library to solve it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isEqualTo(...)` function of AssertJ uses the objects equals method internally to determine equality. Therfore you should override the `equals()` method in your `Money` class. Then you can compare the instances by content instead of object identity, i.e. if the value is the same the instances are considered equal.

The comparison in your `if (expected.current_Money.toString().equals(0.5))` statement doesn't work, because the `expected.current_Money.toString()` part is a string and the `0.5` is auto-boxed to a Double object. Therefore the equals comparison fails because the classes are different.

**Side note**: Whenever you override the `equals()` method you also need to override the `hashcode()` function to match the `equals()` function. Otherwise many classes (e.g. `HashMap`) might misbehave, because they assume that equals and hashcode work based on the same assumptions.

Comment: I am restricted to use     assertThat(expected).isEqualTo(new Money(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5)));

Answer (score 0):

Use `.isEqualByComparingTo()` for assertions with `BigDecimal`